# Evaluate: $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{a} (1+x)^{b} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, gamma-function, beta-function

I want to express
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{a} (1+x)^{b}~ dx
\end{align}
with Gamma functions.

Recall that the beta function is defined as
\begin{align}
B(z_1, z_2) = \int_0^1 t^{z_1-1} (1-t)^{z_2-1} dt = \frac{\Gamma(z_1) \Gamma(z_2)}{\Gamma(z_1+z_2)}
\end{align}
and it seems the above form also has the expressions with Gammas[The above integral comes out of some derivations of Feynman loop integrals and the results are all written in terms of Gamma]

Comment: http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12.E3

Comment: Which substitutions have you tried so far?

Comment: Mathematica gives the solution in closed form

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Other_identities_and_formulas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that beta function can be written as the following form,

$$B(x,y)=\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{x-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}}dt$$

For you integral,

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{a} (1+x)^{b}dx =\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ t^{a}}{ (1+t)^{-b}}dt$$

Compare the parameters

$$x-1=a,~~~x+y=-b$$

Solve it, we get

$$x=a+1,~~~y=-a-b-1$$

therefore,

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{a} (1+x)^{b}dx =B(a+1,-a-b-1)=\frac{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(-a-b-1)}{\Gamma(-b)}$$